# Start python script from excel with input

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I have a Python script (gui.py - a calculation program, written by somebody else). I try to run this from excel with input data from the same excel file. It works fine when I start the script as:

```
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript3
```

In the python script I used the following to get f.ex data from H5 cell, works also fine:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("01.xlsm")
ws = wb.active
mastNumber = ws['H5']
```

But I don't want to edit a lot in  gui.py (have just simple changes) so I planned to use a 2nd script (caller.py) which gets the data from Excel, then I import this to gui.py and there I just use the variable from caller.py. It works also as long as I start gui.py directly. When I start it from Excel I get an error msg.

**error msg**

[image]

So as long as the flow is not Excel -> gui-py -> which imports caller to get data from same Excel file -everything works fine. 
I am open to any solution for this problem or a completely new approach if there is better for somebody with limited programming skills.

Comment: Looking at the error, can you try putting complete path of the excel file at line `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("01.xlsm")` instead of just 01.xlsm.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like you needed full path. With this, it works now.
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'c:\_Data\PyVBA\01.xlsm')

Comment: You're welcome . I have added the answer. Please upvote & mark it as answer, if it has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error, can you try putting complete path of the excel file at line `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("01.xlsm")` instead of just 01.xlsm.